# Can't get networkd-dispatcher scripts working

Tags: netplan, systemd-networkd

I need to disable offloading on my Kubernetes host persistently due to various bugs.

I followed the guide here: https://michael.mulqueen.me.uk/2018/08/disable-offloading-netplan-ubuntu/ but the script isn't getting run. I've put an echo statement saving to disk, and it isn't, so I know it's not being run.

I've put it in /usr/lib/networkd-dispatcher/routable.d in a shell file called 10-disable-offloading and I have also tried: /etc/networkd-dispatcher/routable.d/ and to no avail.

The script is executable and owned by root, I've even given it 777 just to test, and still doesn't run.

networkd-dispatcher is installed already.

I'm testing this on 19.10, but it will also need to run 18.04 as that's what my servers use.

Comment: Hi @brett-jenkins Are you by any chance testing this on your laptop where you'd not have systemd-networkd but network-manager active which then in turn would need NM dispatcher scripts https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/unstable/NetworkManager.html ?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered what I thought was unexpected behaviour for this setup, but it turned out I just wasn't thinking about it right.

My netplan config is something like this:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: no
  bridges:
    br0:
      accept-ra: true
      addresses:
      - 2001:db8:1:2::3/64
      dhcp4: true
      interfaces:
      - eno1
      ipv6-privacy: true
      macaddress: de:ad:be:ef:ca:fe
```

I am using bridge VLAN filters to assign VLANs to interfaces, so they need to run on both the physical NIC and the bridge.  My script in `/etc/networkd-dispatcher/routable.d/` was running on the bridge interface but not the physical NIC.

But `/etc/networkd-dispatcher/routable.d/` is actually the wrong place in this case, because when a NIC is a member of a bridge, it gets no IP address, and therefore never becomes a routable interface.  Putting the script into `/etc/networkd-dispatcher/configured.d/` instead was all that was needed to get my script working on both interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

The missing step is to enable networkd-dispatcher service at boot:

```
# systemctl enable networkd-dispatcher.service
```

Then the next boot scripts will be executed.
To verify they were executed at boot time check journal with:

```
# journalctl -b -u networkd-dispatcher
```